# Using for loop to find specific characters in string

Tags: javascript

I am attempting the [bean counting example in the functions chapter of the book Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html#p_8y74cOkS91). My function is returning a blank.

Without giving me the full answer (I'm working through this example to learn), can someone tell me why my code is not printing any text?"

```
var string = "donkey puke on me boot thar be thar be!";

for (var i = 0; i <= string.length; i++);

function getB(){
  if (string.charAt(i) == "b")
    return i;
  else return "";
}

console.log(getB());
```

Comment: Why does your loop have an empty body? Where would `getB` get its `i` variable from?

Comment: ♫ I am a lonely programmer, `i` ain't got no body.

Comment: Lose the `;` after the `for()`, make the next line `console.log(getB(i))` change to `function getB(i){...`

Comment: if you want to search the location of your string, you can use `string.indexOf("b");` or write your own function which traverses trough the whole string. (use the function as the body for your loop and use just the first condition)

Comment: @RaphaelMüller: Actually that's not the [task](http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html#p_8y74cOkS91)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something wrong about how you're trying to implement this feature.
First of all I think it's better if you have a function that accepts the `string` and the `char` as parameters in order to call it whenever you want.

Example of calling :

```
getChar('this is my custom string', 'c')  -> it should search character `c` in `this is my custom string`

getChar('this is another custom string', 'b')  -> it should search character `b` in `this is another custom string`
```

Example of implementation :

```
var getChar = function(string, char){
  for(var i=0;i<string.length;i++)
  {
    if(string.charAt(i)==char) console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Now, try to make it not case-sensitive  and instead of `console.log` the output try to return a sorted array with character positions

Answer (score 1):

Use This,

```
var string = "donkey puke on me boot thar be thar be!";

for (var i = 0; i <= string.length; i++) {
  if (string.charAt(i) == "b") {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please fix the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

another example: collect all b positions:

```
var string = "donkey puke on me boot thar be thar be!";

function getB(string){
    var placesOfB = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        if (string.charAt(i) == "b") {
            placesOfB.push(i);
        }
    }
    return placesOfB;
}

console.log(getB(string));
```

Comment: Please also fix the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to print every position your value is at, you can program something like this:

```
var string = "donkey puke on me boot thar be thar be!";

for (var i = 0; i <= string.length; i++)
{
   getChar(i, "b");
}

function getChar(i, input)
{
    if (string.charAt(i) == input)
        console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: You'd also want to pass the `string` to that function.

Answer (score 0):

tip: your `for` has no body (putting `;` after it just loops without doing anything)...
and it does not make sense to define a function inside that `for`.

Answer (score 0):

Without giving you the full answer, I'll just give you pointers:
1. Your for loop is not complete - it doesn't do anything.
2. Your getB() function needs to accept string parameter in order to perform some action on it.
3. The if..else statement doesn't have opening and closing brackets {}

Comment: he has a global string which can be accessed from the function scope, also if else statement works fine without brackets if only one line.

Comment: I do agree with that.